# Possible to use self-signed SSL certificate with itms-services

Tags: ios, macos, ssl, deployment, ipa

I'm trying to install a beta app to an iOS device and am hosting the manifest.plist and IPA file on HTTPS with a self-signed certificate. When I hit the itms-services:// link, I get an error of "Cannot connect to <ip address>".

itms-services link:

```
itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://10.0.1.2:1338/ipa/manifest.plist
```

plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>items</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>assets</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>software-package</string>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>https://10.0.1.2:1338/ipa/test.ipa</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
            <key>metadata</key>
            <dict>
                <key>bundle-identifier</key>
                <string>com.company.test</string>
                <key>bundle-version</key>
                <string>1.0</string>
                <key>kind</key>
                <string>software</string>
                <key>title</key>
                <string>test</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding your certificate to the trusted ones (probably, easiest thing to do is to mail a `cer` file to device and open it from standard mail app to install).

Another thing you need to make sure is that your server supports TLS 1.2 and Forward Secrecy.

You can use `nscurl --ats-diagnostics https://example.com/app.ipa` to check if everything done right.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible:

1. Create the certificate file (export as DER encode X.509)
2. Access file from device via HTTP (like the manifest.plist in your example)
3. Agree to install it in device
4. Turn it on: https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT204477